# Is there a concept of Chinese filial peity analogous to 'making your parents proud'?

Tags: ethics, chinese-philosophy, confucius

I understand that Chinese philosophy tends to venerate ancestors and the old. Does any, I suppose Confucian, concept revolve around the everyday notion of making your parents proud?

Comment: There's quite a bit on the Confucian concept of *xiao* 孝, and there's a lot of interpretive arguments about it. I don't recall reading any article that suggested the main focus of this virtue is "making your parents proud," but I do suppose following it ought to have that secondary effect... Could you perhaps expand on your question and explain what's motivating it?

Answer (score 2):

This is hardly an 'everyday notion', but there *is* a focus on glorifying one's parents. In the Book of Filial Piety, Confucius mentinoed that making one's name famous and glorifying one's parents is the end goal of filial piety:

> When we have established our character by the practice of the (filial) course, so as to **make our name famous in future ages and thereby glorify our parents**, this is the end of filial piety. (James Legge's translation, courtesy of [ctext.org](http://ctext.org/pre-qin-and-han?searchu=%E9%A1%AF%E7%88%B6%E6%AF%8D))

The bolded part is 揚名於後世，以顯父母 in Chinese.

Comment: However, Confucius also said: "When right principles of government prevail in the kingdom, he will show himself; when they are prostrated, he will keep concealed." - [Analects 8:13](http://www.sacred-texts.com/cfu/conf1.htm)